# Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad']
Df2 = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['Jake', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony', 'Bob']
```

I want to loop over every row in `Df1['name']` and check if each name is somewhere in `Df2['IDs']`.

The result should return 1 if the name is in there, 0 if it is not like so:

```
Marc  1 
Jake  1
Sam   0 
Brad  0
```

Thank you.

Comment: For those with the same question, who just want the `Boolean` (`True` or `False`), don't use `.astype(int)`. Just use `df1[col].isin(df2[col])`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `isin`

```
Df1.name.isin(Df2.IDs).astype(int)

0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: name, dtype: int32
```

---

Show result in data frame

```
Df1.assign(InDf2=Df1.name.isin(Df2.IDs).astype(int))

   name  InDf2
0  Marc      1
1  Jake      1
2   Sam      0
3  Brad      0
```

---

In a Series object

```
pd.Series(Df1.name.isin(Df2.IDs).values.astype(int), Df1.name.values)

Marc    1
Jake    1
Sam     0
Brad    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: Is it compulsory to include the data type?

Comment: I had such a problem with checking if value in dataframe exists in series or other dataframe! I was getting the error 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed, and no matter how I created the series, it was never immutable. This was the only thing that worked. I couldn't however, get the assign. to create a new column. No error created, but no column.  Df1["InDf2"] = Df1.name.isin... did create the column. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This should do it:

```
Df1 = Df1.assign(result=Df1['name'].isin(Df2['IDs']).astype(int))
```

Comment: This is the solution, if you want to have it in your dataframe, piRSquared solutions only print the results.

Comment: how can I add 1 more condition to above code. For example if there are some values in DF1['name'] for which I want to skip the check @zipa

Answer (score 15):

By using `merge`

```
s=Df1.merge(Df2,left_on='name',right_on='IDs',how='left')
s.IDs=s.IDs.notnull().astype(int)
s
Out[68]: 
   name  IDs
0  Marc    1
1  Jake    1
2   Sam    0
3  Brad    0
```

Answer (score 9):

This is one way. Convert to set for O(1) lookup and use `astype(int)` to represent Boolean values as integers.

```
values = set(Df2['IDs'])

Df1['Match'] = Df1['name'].isin(values).astype(int)
```