# Check if a value in one Dask dataframe is in another Dask dataframe

Tags: dataframe, dask, cross-reference

I found the answer in this post [for pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50449144/12322794)

But when I try to apply it to a Dask dataframe I get a “not implemented” error.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the data into memory, cause dask is lazy loading, it's data not in memory until you execute `compute()`. and function `isin` in `Dask` requires a list-like parameter, not a Dask-object. Official website has instructions as:

> Parameters:   values:set or list-like

So we can change the example of [for pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449088/check-if-value-from-one-dataframe-exists-in-another-dataframe/50449144#50449144) to:

```py
Df1.name.isin(Df2.IDs.compute()).astype(int).compute()

0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Refer: [Dask.compute](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute)