# Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

can some help me how to do this in R Programming?

Pl check the link i have same kind of situation

[Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449088/check-if-value-from-one-dataframe-exists-in-another-dataframe/62756988?noredirect=1#comment110980989_62756988)

Comment: yes the but the link you shared is in python, the answer is in python but i need it in R programming

Comment: the link you shared is right one for python , the first answer of @piRSquared is given in python ... i am trying to bring the same result using R

Comment: Please post data in a format that R can understand.

Comment: I think the history and connection to Python is not relevant and that it would be best if your wrote up the complete question with some reproducible R data and clear example of expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same data and outcome as the original Python example

```r
Df1 <- data.frame(name =  c('Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad'))
Df2 <- data.frame(IDs = c('Jake', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony', 'Bob'))
Df1$presentinDf2 <- as.integer(Df1$name %in% Df2$IDs)
Df1
#>   name presentinDf2
#> 1 Marc            1
#> 2 Jake            1
#> 3  Sam            0
#> 4 Brad            0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use anti_join from the dplyr package to create a new dataframe with the duplicate information between the datasets.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name =  c('Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad'))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c('Jake', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony', 'Bob'))
diff <- anti_join(df2, df1, by = "name")

> diff
  name
1 John
2 Tony
3  Bob
```