# Creating a column in one DF that compares another column from other DF in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two datasets that I need to see how many names are different in one dataset to another. I used this question for reference and the code I used only found 1 issue is there are others.

[Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449088/check_if-value-from-one-dataframe-exists-in-another-dataframe)

```
DF1   
Name: 'Adam', 'Ben', 'Chris', 'Dave', 'Emily'

DF2
Manager: 'Adam', 'Beth', 'Jack', 'Grace', 'Mel', 'Emily', 'Chris'
```

I am trying to find a method that will create a new column indicating when names match or not.

Desired Output:

```
Adam    1
Ben     0
Chris   1
Dave    0
Emily   1
```

This is the code used.

```
df3 = df2.assighn(indf1=df2.Manager.isin(df1.Name).astype(int))
```

Any suggestions?

DF1

```
 name         id      position_num       job_title    
Lawrence    00010293      62121         Analytic Supervisor 
Richard     00023723      73213         Lead Data Manger
Elizabeth   00024422      42392         Analytic Director
Nicole      00012123      23423         Data Management Manger 
Timothy     00032112      32134         Business Execution Manager
```

Comment: Mind providing your `DF` and `DF2` as `DF.to_dict()` and `DF2.to_dict()` ?

Comment: I can provide a small sample the datasets are both 50,000 plus rows and 25+ columns

Comment: Sure! `DF.head(5)` will do

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? You just used it in the wrong direction: `df1.assign(indf2=df1['Name'].isin(df2['Manager']).astype(int))`

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to paste so I made a quick dataset on the question @rafaelc

Comment: @Coding_Nubie you haven't answered my comment, what if wrong with your current code? AFAIK it works well if you swap the two Series

Comment: @mozway Sorry, the issue was I was using the wrong column in my data it is fixed now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
names = df1['Name'].values
manager_name = df2['Manager'].values

matched_names = {name: manager_name.count(name) for name in names}
for name, count in matched_names:
  print("we have {} of {}".format(count, name)
```

Output will be:

```
we have 1 of Adam
we have 0 of Ben
we have 1 of Chris
we have 0 of Dave
we have 1 of Emily
```

Also the `matched_names` will be like this:

```
matched_names = {'Adam':1, 'Ben':0, 'Chris':1, 'Dave':0, 'Emily':1}
```

Comment: It should work for you but if you got an error please inform me so I can help.

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution, if the two inputs were larger this would scale badly. OP already provided the correct approach in the question, just used it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` but you have to swap `df1` and `df2`:

```
df3 = df1.assign(indf2=df1.Name.isin(df2.Manager).astype(int))
print(df3)

# Output
    Name  indf2
0   Adam      1
1    Ben      0
2  Chris      1
3   Dave      0
4  Emily      1
```